# How to change placeholder's font-size but don't change the value's font-size in <input> by CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to change placeholder's font-size but don't change the value's font-size in `<input>` by CSS ?

When I focus on the `<input>`, placeholder's font size is already 12px, and then the value I input will be 16px. Just like this.

**When I focus on the `<input>`**

[image]

**When I edit**

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some example code if you have any? Any specifics you can provide make your question easier to answer.

Comment: @ChristianJuth I will pay attention next time. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this answer:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-size: 16px; }
::-moz-placeholder { font-size: 16px; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { font-size: 16px; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder { font-size: 16px; }

input 
{
font-size:8px;
height:30px;
width:50%;
text-indent:10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="Enter the name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
.your-class::-webkit-input-placeholder, .your-class::-moz-placeholder, .your-class:-ms-input-placeholder, .your-class:-moz-placeholder{
   font-size: 16px;
 }
```

or '*' for all placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css)

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-size: 16px; }
::-moz-placeholder { font-size: 16px; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { font-size: 16px; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder { font-size: 16px; }
```